# Installing Tensorflow using Anaconda Navigator gives UnsatisfiableError for Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda

I'm getting the following error while trying to install Tensorflow using Anaconda Navigator.

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - anaconda==2018.12=py37_0 -> bleach==3.0.2=py37_0
  - anaconda==2018.12=py37_0 -> mkl-service==1.1.2=py37hb782905_5
  - anaconda==2018.12=py37_0 -> numexpr==2.6.8=py37hdce8814_0
  - anaconda==2018.12=py37_0 -> scikit-learn==0.20.1=py37h343c172_0
  - tensorflow
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Earlier I installed Tensorflow using Anaconda Navigator for python 3.6. It worked perfectly. This time it is not working.

I searched for solution but everyone has done it for python 3.6. I'm not sure what are the changes I need to make for python 3.7. It would be of great help if anyone can give the answer or give the link to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

There may not be a build for 3.7 in the Anaconda channel/repo.

Since you're using the visual interface of Anaconda Navigator I'll provide a visual, rather than the command line, approach.

Go to anaconda.org and [search for tensorflow](https://anaconda.org/search?q=tensorflow).

On the results page...

1. Find the Channel from which you're downloading.
2. Verify the version you want is available in that channel.
3. Verify the platform you're using is available.

[image: anaconda.org tensorflow search]

If all those things meet your expectations then click the package name and go to the File tab.
https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow/files

On this page it's easy to verify if a build with your desired Python version exists.
Use "find" in the browser and search for `37`.

[image: anaconda Files tab]

#### TLDR

In this case, as of today, there is no build for Python 3.7.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Now I tried downgrading to python 3.6 using conda install python=3.6. Then installed tensorflow using conda. But after activating tensorflow when I'm checking I'm getting "no module named tensorflow" error. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Have you activated the conda environment you installed tensorflow into? From Anaconda Prompt type `conda activate <env name>`

Comment: Yes. I followed all the instructions mentioned. I installed Anaconda version 5.1.

Comment: Wish I could help. Sorry. Maybe post a new question with the details of the current problem? I think this answer is correct for this question. You'll get there eventually! 